# Only allow first letter to be capitalized in string (regex)

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

```
function toTitleCase(str){
    var styleName = $("a.monogramClassSelected").attr("styleKey");
        if (styleName == 'script') {
        return str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt){return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();}).replace(/\s/, '');
        } else {
        return str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt){return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();});
        }

}
```

This works (thanks to help below) - to remove spaces and have the first letter capitalized.

However, I need different functionality and did not frame my question correctly the first time.

I need to use regex to only allow the first letter to be capitalized. The string replace method above does not work fully, as a user can get around the method by using a space. So they could have "To Two". I need to rework the regex to only allow the first letter to be capitalized, regardless of spaces. (and the first letter does not have to be capitalized)

thanks for everyone's help so far!

Comment: What syntax errors are you getting?

Comment: Javascript does not support titlecase, so this mission is impossible.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide a list of sample input and the corresponding replaced string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This will do it:**

```
function UppercaseFirst(str) {
    str = str.replace(/^\s+/, '');
    str = str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.substr(1);
    return str
}

var mystring = " this is a test";

alert(UppercaseFirst(mystring));
```

Comment: edited, now it should do what you what (Even if there are spaces first)

Answer (score 1):

This regular expression replaces all sequences of the form zero or *exactly* one space followed by capital letter by only the letter while keeping the rest of the text untouched (with multiple spaces allowed)

```
str.replace(/\s{0,1}([A-Z])(\s*\w*)/g, '$1$2');
```

The groups can be accessed by $1 and $2 in the replacement string.

[image: regex explaination]

**Sample**

**Input** " A person Who never made a mistake never tried anything new. - Albert Einstein :)"

**Replaced string** "A personWho never made a mistake never tried anything new. -AlbertEinstein :)"

In case you want to remove mutiple spaces instead of zero or one space preceding a capital letter then use `\s*` instead of `\s{0,1}` in the above expression.

Comment: doesn't work in this context `  return str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt){return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();}).replace(/\s{0,1}([A-Z])(\s*\w*)/g, '$1$2');`

Comment: Where did you get such nice looking example from? Is there a website that shows regEx like that?

Comment: @hbtest, the regex was created in [Expresso 3.0](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm) and the quote is from [Brainy Quote](http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/authors/a/albert_einstein.html). The image is simply a modified screen shot from expresso.

Answer (score 0):

To just remove the spaces, this works for me:

```
function toTitleCase(str){
    str = str.replace(/\s[A-Z]/, '');
    // str = str.replace(/[A-Z]\s/, '');
    return str;
}
```

Comment: this is kind of working. I still need to allow spaces, just not a space/capital letter combination (in that order). For example " T" is not allowed. But "T " is.

Comment: ya, i know thats why i commented the second line. check the answer

Comment: ah. It is working, however I did not clarify my question enough. See edit.